# Can a set of infinite groups be elementary class instead of elementary class in the wider sense?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

For any integer $k\geq 2,$ one can find a sentence $\lambda_k$ which translates 'there are at least $k$ things.'
For example, 
$$\lambda_2=\exists v_1 \exists v_2 (v_1\neq v_2),$$
$$\lambda_3 = \exists v_1 \exists v_2 \exists v_3 (v_1\neq v_2 \wedge v_2\neq v_3 \wedge v_1\neq v_3),$$
and etc.

It is well known that the class of all infinite groups is an elementary class in the wider sense, denoted as $EC_\Delta,$ because it is a model of conjunction of the groups axioms together with $\{\lambda_2,\lambda_3,...\}$

> **Question:** Instead of taking $\{\lambda_2,\lambda_3,...\},$ can we take conjunction of all $\lambda_2,\lambda_3,...$ so that the class of all infinite groups becomes an elementary class with a sentence being conjunction of all groups axioms and all $\lambda$'s?

Comment: Is that conjunction a sentence in first-order logic?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I guess no?

Answer (score 3):

First-order logic doesn't allow infinite conjunctions, so your proposed definition doesn't work. But this doesn't show that *no* such definition works, so the question "Is the class of infinite groups axiomatizable by a single sentence?" isn't answered by that.

However, it isn't hard to show that the answer is in fact "no," by compactness: if $\varphi$ is true in exactly the infinite groups, then $\neg\varphi$ is true in exactly the finite groups - but there are arbitrarily large finite groups ...